# How to run a Unit-Test for ESP32 without flashing it?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, arduino, esp32, platformio

Knowing from other languages and platforms we want to use Unit-Testing during the Build-Process BEFORE the code is flashed to the hardware. This should be possible for simple functions tests which have no need for the ESP32 hardware.

But as we understand yet the C++ code is compiled (and linked) for the ESP32 chip and shall not run on the developing system or in a CI/CD pipeline.

Is there any way to emulate ESP32 (for C++) or run Unit-Tests on any other way on another systems?

---

note: We are using 'platformio' for the build.

Comment: It seems you are looking for an [ESP32 emulator](https://github.com/tflander/esp32-machine-emulator).

Comment: Code that does not depend on hardware can be unit-tested with frameworks like googletest. You can add it as a separate make target (i.e. `make test` to run those).

Comment: @nada I forget to tell we are using C++ and this Emulator says: "test-drive (TDD) your MicroPython code".

Comment: @rustyx So the idea is to compile it twice? First for the current machine with running the unit-tests and then for the ESP32 environment. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do this with the [qemu_esp32](https://github.com/espressif/qemu) emulator. You can compile your test runner and run it directly on the emulator instead of flashing it to a real esp32 chip.

Here is an example of how to do this (adapted from [esp32_qemu_unity_test_action](https://github.com/Batov/esp32_qemu_unity_test_action)):

1. Compile the test runner like you normally would. Before you proceed you might want to actually flash this just to know your test runner and tests are working.

```
idf.py build
cd build
```

2. Normally when you flash a esp32, you're writing several binary files to specific locations. This command merges all those into a single full binary image.

```
esptool.py --chip esp32 merge_bin --fill-flash-size 4MB -o flash_image.bin @flash_args
```

3. Run the esp32 emulator and provide the full binary flash image.

```
/opt/qemu/bin/qemu-system-xtensa -nographic -no-reboot -machine esp32 -drive file=flash_image.bin,if=mtd,format=raw -serial file:output.log
```

By specifying `-no-reboot`, the emulator will simply exit instead of rebooting.